# Convert .wav to .mp3 with specific codec using LAME

Tags: linux, macos, ffmpeg, format, audio-conversion

I have two audio files, One is .mp3 format ( extension is .wav but the file is .mp3 ) and other is actual .wav format. I am trying to convert actual .wav format same as first .mp3 file.

[First .mp3 file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FrxpZCGl3sLSmJRYR9VtRai8RUTjaAFb/view?usp=sharing)

```
General
Complete name                            : count.wav
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
File size                                : 183 KiB
Duration                                 : 9 s 360 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 160 kb/s
Writing library                          : LAME3.99.5
FileExtension_Invalid                    : m1a mpa mpa1 mp1 m2a mpa2 mp2 mp3

Audio
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Format settings                          : Joint stereo / MS Stereo
Duration                                 : 9 s 360 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 160 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 41.667 FPS (1152 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 183 KiB (100%)
Writing library                          : LAME3.99.5
```

[Second .wav file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ogTBXsTzEK_rM4blQX8IE5bOkKO_WDh-/view?usp=sharing)

```
General
Complete name                            : second_file.wav
Format                                   : Wave
File size                                : 1.41 MiB
Duration                                 : 15 s 445 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 768 kb/s

Audio
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Codec ID                                 : 1
Duration                                 : 15 s 445 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 768 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Stream size                              : 1.41 MiB (100%)
```

I am trying to convert second file in the first format with all the encoding, bits and other audio features same as first audio.

My LAME version was 3.100, someone suggested you should get LAME3.99.5 since first audio is written using that one. I have installed LAME3.99.5 on my macos and tried this command :

```
lame -b 160 -h second_file.wav converted.mp3
```

output file info :

```
General
Complete name                            : converted.mp3
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
File size                                : 303 KiB
Duration                                 : 15 s 480 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 160 kb/s
Writing library                          : LAME3.99r

Audio
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Duration                                 : 15 s 480 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 160 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 41.667 FPS (1152 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 302 KiB (100%)
Writing library                          : LAME3.99r
Encoding settings                        : -m m -V 4 -q 2 -lowpass 20.5 -b 160
```

Is it exactly same as first file or am I losing some info and making any mistake?

I also tried to convert both files in .mp3 using ffmpeg

```
General
Complete name                            : s1.mp3
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
File size                                : 147 KiB
Duration                                 : 9 s 384 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 128 kb/s
Writing library                          : LAME3.100

Audio
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Format settings                          : Joint stereo / MS Stereo
Duration                                 : 9 s 384 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 41.667 FPS (1152 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 147 KiB (100%)
Writing library                          : LAME3.100
```

Second file after conversion using ffmpeg

```
General
Complete name                            : s2.mp3
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
File size                                : 121 KiB
Duration                                 : 15 s 480 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 64.0 kb/s
Writing library                          : Lavf58.29.100

Audio
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Duration                                 : 15 s 480 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 64.0 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 41.667 FPS (1152 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 121 KiB (100%)
```

As you can see there are few differences in both audios. How to scale both audio formats at one format with all the features ( bit rate, sampling etc ) should be same in both.

Comment: One is stereo, the other mono. They will never have the same parameters. 128kb/s stereo is the same as 64kb/s mono. Twice the channels, twice the apparent rate.

Comment: I have to scale them and make it at one level, How can I? Which format should I choose to convert both of them?

Comment: "scale them and make it at one level" That's an entirely different question, nothing to do with your encoding. 'level' is also a very broad definition - you mean Peak, RMS, LUFS??

Comment: No, I am working on a classification problem, Here are full details https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/68717/how-to-deal-with-different-audio-formats-for-audio-classification

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue what any of that means. I'm a sound engineer not a coder I push faders & twiddle knobs… someone else figures out how to make them do what they do ;)